# What is the proper format for HTTP POST Dynamic Zone data with Strapi API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, backend, strapi

I have a Strapi user collection that looks like this.
[image: Strapi User Data]
[image: More Strapi User Data]

I am trying to use the API to create a new user with the "AdditionalInfo" dynamic zone filled with "StudentUserInfos" component.

What would my HTTP POST request Body look like?
I can not find documentation or example on how to do it anywhere. I have tried:

```
{
   "username" : "string",
   "password" : "string",
   "email" : "string",
   "AdditionalInfo": [
    {
      "__component": "user-type.student-user",
      "Address": "string",
      "ParentsName": "string",
      "ParentsPhoneNumber": "string",
      "SchoolName": "string",
      "OtherInfo": "string"
    }]
```

It gives me a Bad Request response. What is the proper format for this? Can you please point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little bit, you should send your JSON like this:

```json
{
    "...otherFields"
    "industry": "61f83aa80f6439632bac3579",
    "additional_info": [
        {
            "__component": "fields.seller-fields",
            "country": {
                "isoCode": "US",
                "name": "United States"
            },
            "state": {
                "isoCode": "CA",
                "name": "California"
            },
            "year_established": 2022,
            "size": "10000+"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where "additional_info" is the name of the dynamic zone and "fields.seller-fields" the name of the component. I would recommend creating a dummy dynamic zone through Strapi GUI and then fetching it and seeing how dynamic zones are stored. (That's how I figured out the name of the component). Check the image below

[strapi dynamic zones example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUAze.png)